# SP 2013 Calculated Column that groups data choices

Tags: 2013, data, grouping

I am having trouble adding a calculated column that groups the data from the previous column into separate teams. 
I was thinking that the 
IF(*[column1]*='A' 'B' 'C')THEN('Team1')
IF(*[column1]*='D' 'E' 'F')THEN('Team2')
IF(*[column1]*='G' 'H' 'I')THEN('Team3')

I am not familiar with formula writing, so sorry. But I hope this gives an idea of what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Tip: always start in Excel with Formulas, they are almost identical, and allow you to try/develop fast

Answer (score 2):

You will need to use OR with IF in order to achieve this. It will be something like this:

```
=IF( OR(Title="A" , OR(Title="B",Title="C"))
     ,"Team 1"
     ,IF( OR(Title="D" , OR(Title="E",Title="F"))
          ,"Team 2"
          ,IF( OR(Title="G" , OR(Title="H",Title="I"))
               ,"Team 3"
               ,"")))
```

More details about IF, AND & OR is [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb862071(v=office.14).aspx)

A better version based on @Danny's suggestion:

```
=IF(OR(Title="A",Title="B",Title="C"),"Team 1",IF(OR(Title="D",Title="E",Title="F"),"Team 2",IF(OR(Title="G",Title="H",Title="I"),"Team 3","")))
```

For all Functions that work in SharePoint see: http://www.viewmaster365.com/365coach/#/Calculated_Column_Functions_List

Comment: @Matt, now you mark his answer as the correct one, that is how StackOverflow works. Note that ``OR()`` is a function, that can take up to 30 parameters, so ``OR( Title="A" ,  Title="B" , Title="C" ) `` is valid and shorter

Comment: PS. Since SharePoint considers 0 False and any other number True, you could also use the FIND function which returns an index (0 = not found): ``IF( FIND( Title , "ABC" ) , "Team 1" , ....``